# Delete Imageview on timer

Tags: android, timer, imageview

I have a code like that this, I want to delete the imageview after I clicked on it. I use relative layout. What must I do?
I must DELETE it not hide it because I have many imageview and I want to destroy it so the program can work faster.

```
banyakmusuh= new CountDownTimer(50000,1500) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Random a = new Random();
        int posisix = a.nextInt(500);
        btn = new ImageView(level2.this);
        btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.salju);
        i= i+1;
        btn.setId(i);                               
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(posisix, 0, 0, 0);
        btn.setLayoutParams(params);
        RelativeLayout linearLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.tingkat2);                 
        linearLayout.addView(btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    data.nilai+=10;
                    TextView score1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.skore);
                    score1.setText(String.valueOf(data.nilai));
                //what the code for delete imageview? 
                //some people say to write this code but it cant, there are a green line when i debug it 
               //((RelativeLayout)v.getParent()).removeView(v);
                                }
                            });

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            //banyakmusuh.start();
                        }
                    }.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android works on Java. You can't destroy or delete an object in java. You can only say to the java machine that the machine is free to destroy the object if needed.

Yes, I think, you should start by `removeView(btn)`. But don't forget also to set `btn=null`. Thus you are telling the java machine that the memory could be freed.

Comment: what about remove view? 
i have a problem sir
i have a simple game that we must click the imageview .. if theres so many mageview and i dont delete it the program will running so slow .. how to slove it sir?

Comment: I have edited the answer. I am glad to help, feel free to ask, and I am not "sir", friend :-). As for program running slow, look also at optimization pages in android developer pages http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/search/label/Optimization

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to the specific view, you can use:

```
yourRelativeLayout.removeView(imageViewToRemove);
```

I would do:

```
// I would consider renaming your layout, btw
final RelativeLayout linearLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.tingkat2);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v)
               {
                   linearLayout.removeView(btn);
               }
             });
```

Comment: thanks i will rename my layout .. 
it doesnt work .. when i click the imageview theres a classfile editor shown .. :(

Comment: Well, technically that should remove it from the view. But, I guess as a workaround, you could try: setBackgroundDrawable(null);   The ImageView will still remain in memory since the view has a reference to it, but at least the image data will no longer be there. However, that removeView should have worked and you may have a worse problem if that didn't solve it for you

Comment: but if the imageview remain theres a new problem ..because i want set collision imageview with antoher imageview ..if the imageview still remain it cause looping collisions .. =(

Comment: Maybe add a check for visibility to exclude any views that aren't visible: if(view.isShown())